# Can not change value in textbox when edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the Page-Load method I set value for textbox like this

```
txtid.Value = pro.getId().ToString();
txtmodel.Text = pro.getModal();
txtname.Text = pro.getName();
cbCategory.SelectedValue = pro.getCategory();
txtprice.Text = pro.getPrice().ToString();
txtDescription.Text = pro.getDescription();
```

and when I submit to edit the Product I get value

```
string id = txtid.Value.ToString();
string modal = txtmodel.Text.ToString();
int category = int.Parse(cbCategory.SelectedValue);
string name = txtname.Text.ToString();
string description = txtDescription.Text.ToString();
```

and I try to change value different with the original but when I bug it's still keep original value and save to database.

Comment: replace txtid.Value  with txtid.Text...

Comment: @PranayRana it can be a hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

where are you setting these values on `page load` this may be the reason.

set inside `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

 As follows

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     txtid.Value = pro.getId().ToString();
     txtmodel.Text = pro.getModal();
     txtname.Text = pro.getName();
     cbCategory.SelectedValue = pro.getCategory();
     txtprice.Text = pro.getPrice().ToString();
     txtDescription.Text = pro.getDescription();
}
```

and why are you using `txtid.Value` is it a `hidden-field`?

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net for every click event the page will be postback so put the code in if(!ispostback)
preasent in page load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     txtid.Value = pro.getId().ToString();
     txtmodel.Text = pro.getModal();
     txtname.Text = pro.getName();
     cbCategory.SelectedValue = pro.getCategory();
     txtprice.Text = pro.getPrice().ToString();
     txtDescription.Text = pro.getDescription();
}
```